# Error on DSL Connection

Tags: debian, networking, linux-mint, networkmanager

I tried to DSL connection on my laptop. I use Debian mint. I used username and password too. But when I click on the icon it shows

```
"Unable to connect DSL with error "(1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/28' failed in libnm-glib."
```

After that, I tried `sudo pppoeconf` in the terminal . But it says, `"pppoeconf command not found"`

I assume, I have to install pppoeconf. But how do I do it when my connection is not working . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case go to some other machine which has the download capability and download `pppoeconf` Install it and read the man-page, has everything that you possibly may need.